# Informal definition of the real projective line $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

In his book [Four pillars of geometry](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-387-29052-4), John Stillwell defines informally (p. 107):

> "[The real projective line] is the set $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$
>   *together with* all the linear fractional functions mapping $\mathbb{R}
>  \cup \{\infty\}$ onto itself."

Linear fractional functions are the functions $f(x) = \frac{ax + b}{cx +d}$ with $ad - bc \neq 0$. I wonder what *together with* does mean?

While the real line is just $\mathbb{R}$, it's clear what a point on the real line is: just an element $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

(Why don't we define the real line to be $\mathbb{R}$ *together with* the isometries $f(x) = \pm x + a$ - or do we implicitely do?)

Once again:

> What does *together with* mean precisely and formally? Something like
>   $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^1 = \langle \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\},
>  LF\rangle$ with $LF = \{f(x) = (ax+b)/(cx +d)\ |\ a,b,c,d \in
>  \mathbb{R}, ad - bc \neq 0\}$?

If $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^1$ thus is an ordered pair of sets, what then is an element of resp. point on $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^1$ considered as a set?

(Better might be $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^1 = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\} \times
 LF$, thus an element of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^1$ would be a pair $\langle x, f(\cdot)\rangle$ with $x \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ and $f(\cdot) \in LF$.)

If it suffices to define the real line to be $\mathbb{R}$, why doesn't it suffice to define the real projective line to be $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$?